# getHierarchyViewer() throws NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: android

I am trying to get android HierarchyViewer via the IChimpDevice, my code looks like this

```
public HierarchyViewer GetHierarchyViewer()
{
    return mDevice.getHierarchyViewer();
}
```

I have initialized the mDevice this way:

```
mDevice = mChimpchat.waitForConnection(TIMEOUT, ".*");
if ( mDevice == null ) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Couldn't connect.");
}
mDevice.wake();
```

And when I call `getHierarchyViewer()`, I get this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/android/hierarchyviewerlib/device/DeviceBridge
    at com.android.chimpchat.hierarchyviewer.HierarchyViewer.setupViewServer(HierarchyViewer.java:46)
    at com.android.chimpchat.hierarchyviewer.HierarchyViewer.<init>(HierarchyViewer.java:42)
    at com.android.chimpchat.adb.AdbChimpDevice.getHierarchyViewer(AdbChimpDevice.java:96)
    at ChimpChatWrapper.GetHierarchyViewer(ChimpChatWrapper.java:44)
    at ViewService.main(ViewService.java:17)
```

Can someone help explain why the DeviceBridge class may not be found?